# Can a module used in an article have parameters?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-module, module-params

Im quite new to joomla. As far as I understood, modules can be used in an article like building blocks. Example:

```
{loadmoduleid 117}
```

### Goal

I would like to give article authors a simple method to add unified features to an article without needing to create a new module for example for a small image gallery or specialised item list.

### Question

Is it possible to provide parameters to a module? For example a link to an image and a text string:

```
{loadmoduleid 117 | /images/myimage.jpg| This is my image}
```

The module should the be able to scan parameters and place them for example in an html template like this:

```
<img src="$PARAM1" alt="$PARAM2">
```

The resulting code would be

```
<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" alt="This is my image">
```

### Note

Please note: my question may be poiting in the wrong direction. There may already exist a different mechanism for achieving my desired result.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Georg. Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.  Do you need to load a module? Could you perhaps like to load an article instead? Can you give a bit more context about your goal?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I have added a little more information on my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Parameters are defined in the module instance with the given ID. You'd need a custom shortcode plugin to pass any parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Is there another solution that may be used to achieve what I want?